# Do you take the negative square root when you raise a number to the power of a half?

Tags: exponentiation, fractions

E.g. does $4^{1/2} =  \pm 2$ and if not, why?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: the (accepted) answer to that question is wrong. But never mind, I have posted a better one :-)

Comment: @TonyK I don't see anything wrong with the answer. They simply omitted the conclusion that to get both solutions, you do, in fact, need the $\pm$ sign.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: No, it's worse than that. They seem to  assume that if $x=t^2$, then $t=x^{1/2}$.

Comment: @TonyK I don't see any mention of $x=t^2\Rightarrow t=x^{1/2}$ in the answer.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: Well, the answer mentions $t^{3/2}$, which doesn't occur anywhere in the question. So it wasn't really possible to follow the question's notation exactly. But disentangling, it seems to assume that if $x^3=y^2$, then $y=x^{3/2}$. Which is false.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97318/discussion-between-simply-beautiful-art-and-tonyk).

Answer (score 0):

$\sqrt{4}=2$ not $-2$ because the range of $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$  $x\in[0,\infty)$ is $[0,\infty)$ therefore $4^{1/2}=2$

Also $\sqrt{(2)^2}=\vert 2 \vert =2$
And $\sqrt{(-2)^2}=\vert -2 \vert =2$
So $\sqrt{4}=2$

Comment: The range is $[0,\infty)$ by convention.  The reality is square roots have two solutions.

Comment: This answer doesn't really explain anything.